# Executing Batch script in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, ssis

I have a SSIS Package, in which I want to execute a batch script. Thing is that it all runs smooth when I execute it manually in the package itself. However, if I set up a job in SSMS and run the job from there, it just keeps running, it never stops. The downside of that is that there is no error message, which makes debugging this more complex.

I know for most people this is absolutely impossible to answer based on this info. I guess I am hoping that someone has experienced the same thing and somehow found a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Regards, M.

Comment: Does the Agent service/ proxy account have enough permissions to run the batch script? It does however seem odd that you don't receive an error.

Comment: Another solution would be to convert your bat file to .exe and use a "CmdExec Job Step" and not use a ssis package at all.  Maybe that could help?

Comment: @Holder Thanks for the suggestion. The Exe option did not work. However, you pointed me in the right direction. When I call the batch file via a Power Shell task, it does run. Side-effect is that my timestamp %DATE% is literally in the filename now as a string. But one step closer! Thanks!

Comment: Could you temporarily add some logging, i.e. writing to a text file, to the script so that you can track its progress and narrow down where it is hanging up?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure (been at least a year since I've touched SSIS) but I seem to remember that you need to make sure that the script gives back an ExitCode, where 0 means success.

So the last line could be:

```
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this does not work for me, same issue.